# Low rank approximation

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, computer-algebra, toric-varieties, groebner-bases

Can we solve low rank approximation problem by using concept of Gröbner basis? I was trying to find it by Macaulay2 but didn't find the answer. I was trying to do by toric ideals as for them Gröbner basis finding is less complex. Am I on right track?

Comment: Is there a notion of Gröbner basis that works in real algebraic geometry?  If so then the answer to your question must be Yes, though it might be impractical because of the computational complexity of Gröbner bases.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies The real algebraic geometry analogue is [cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition).